# Serre subcategories of the category of chain complexes of modules

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.

Let $R$ be a commutative $k$-algebra.

We denote by $\operatorname{Mod}(R), C(R), $ and $ D(R)$ the category of $R$-modules, the category of chain complexes of $R$-modules, and the derived category of $R$-modules, respectively.

Then, it is well-known that the Serre subcategories of $\operatorname{Mod}(R)$ and the thick subcategories of $D(R)$ are classified by Gabriel and many other mathematicians in many ways.
In particular, notions related to $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$  are useful (for example, specialization closed subset, etc.).

**Question**
Are there some results about classifications of the Serre subcategories of $C(R)$?

Moreover, let $S$ be a commutative differential graded algebra over $k$.
Then, are there some results about classifications of the Serre (resp. thick) subcategories of the category of dg-$S$ modules (resp. derived category of dg-$S$ modules) $C(S)$ (resp. $D(S)$).

**Edit(10/5)**  The above questions are open or not?

Any comment is welcome. Thank you!

See also the helpful comments below.

Comment: Chain complexes are modules for R[d]/d^2, so any general theorem about modules applies. Do you want something more?

Comment: Thank you. What does $R[d]/d^2$ mean?

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon I don't think this immediately solves the problem. Chain complexes embed in R[d]/d^2-mod ( or graded modules, but perhaps you can just add another generator ), and indeed every theorem about internal properties of chain complexes follow from a general module theory, but if as this is not an equivalence you have to be careful. A Serre subcategory of R[d]/d^2-mod can intersect (or not) the corresponding embedded category of chain complexes and might not be a Serre subcategory of this subcategory.

Comment: @Walterfield If you're considering chain complexes over R, John means the ring of dual numbers over R, so the quotient of the polynomial ring R[d] by the ideal generated by d^2

Comment: @AT0 I suppose some care should be taken re the grading, but in my experience, any theorem worth applying will be happy to respect a grading!

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon and AT0 Thank you. Regarding chain complexes of R-mods as R[d]/d^2-mods is a well-known method? Are there any references or other information that demonstrates the usefulness of this approach?

Comment: @Walterfield Wiebel's book has a remark about it, or maybe it's an exercise.

Comment: I have found an explanation in Example 1.6.14 of the book. (but the algebra mentioned in the example seem to be slightly different from what you said?)

Comment: Is my question open after all?

Comment: A partial answer to your question about DG-algebras is given in https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.05190 where there is a classification of localizing and colocalizing (and thick subcategories of perfects) for commutative DG-algebras which are noetherian, non-positive, and with bounded cohomology

Comment: Do you want some finiteness condition (e.g., Noetherian) on $R$? I don't think that the claims in your fourth paragraph about the existence of classifications of Serre/thick subcategories are true for arbitrary commutative $k$-algebras,

Comment: @JeremyRickard I would like to consider the general case in the end, but initially I would like to consider it under the noetherian condition.